# spring download test suites

Tags: spring

How do i download the test suites that spring developers wrote. I found this site http://git.springsource.org/sandbox/cbeams/trees/5519df3491b0c420f312253348fb93110aea99d3/org.springframework.expression/src/test/java/org/springframework/expression/spel but not sure how to download it to my drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At provided page exists link "Download as 5519df34 tar.gz"

But better to find and download tests from SpringSource github account: https://github.com/SpringSource/